# cast from 'mdlmaterialproperty?!' to unrelated type NSArray always fails

Tags: ios, swift

```
let arraySnapUserYesStatus=responseDic["response"]!["snapUser"] as! NSArray
```

When running my old Project
got warning "cast from 'mdlmaterialproperty?!' to unrelated type NSArray always fails" and when run exception occur on this line.

I have tried to find the Sollution But I didnt get the Solution.

Comment: can you sjow the response  of responseDic

Comment: Look in the documentation of the class or the response object what type the value for `snapUser` is. The error message says it's  `mdlmaterialproperty` (probably spelled with some capital letters) so casting to `NSArray` *always fails*. And always fails means the app will reliably crash.

Comment: {
    message = "No snaplog";
    requestKey = snaplogdetails;
    response =     {
        cash =         (
        );
        snapChat =         (
        );
        snapUser =         (
        );
    };
    status = SUCCESS;
}

Comment: Its just because of When installed SCRecorder by cocoapods, Please any one help